# NestJS can't resolve a service dependency

Tags: node.js, dependency-injection, nestjs

I am trying to inject a `ContentsService` into a `SlackModule` so that I can use some of the Content functions in my Slack Controller.

This is app.module

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ContentsModule,
    ZapierModule,
    SlackModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here is my Contents Module:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

import { ContentsController, ZapierController, SlackInteractiveController } from './contents.controller';
import { ContentsService } from './contents.service';
import { ContentSchema } from './content.model';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Content', schema: ContentSchema }]),
  ],
  controllers: [ContentsController, ZapierController, SlackInteractiveController],
  providers: [ContentsService],
  exports: [ContentsService],
})
export class ContentsModule {}
```

This is my Slack Module:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { SlackService } from './slack.service';
import { SlackController } from './slack.controller';
import { ContentsService } from '../contents/contents.service';

@Module({
  providers: [SlackService],
  controllers: [SlackController],
  imports: [ContentsService],
}) 
export class SlackModule {}
```

And my Slack Controller

```
import { ContentsService } from '../contents/contents.service'

@Controller('slackevents')
export class SlackController {  
  constructor(private contentsService: ContentsService) {}
```

But when I run this code, I get this error:

> [Nest] 75628   - 05/22/2020, 7:08 AM   [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ContentsService (?). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the ContentsService context. +44ms\

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services and other providers do not belong in the `imports` array. Only module classes should go in there. You should have `imports: [ContentsModule]` in your `SlackModule` and you'll have access to the `ContentsService`